# get a list of apps who use accessibility service

Tags: android, adb

I'm working on an old android device that has a hidden accessibility service that closes 3rd party apps, so I went to uninstall this app but I don't know which app it is

so How can I get a list of all packages that request accessibility permission in the manifest
using `ADB shell`

Comment: do you have a root access on this device?

Comment: no on this device I don't have root access